# usage of void put_page(struct page *page) in Linux

Tags: c, linux

I trace Linux source code and find this function: `void put_page(struct page *page)`

I Googled it and some people say this function use to construct a map from physical frame address to virtual address.

But I trace the `put_page` function in `mm/swap.c`. The code behavior seems not used for mapping physical to virtual address.

Any one know what this function do?

Comment: Why not include a link to the code you're asking about: http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/mm/swap.c#L231

Answer (score 2):

In the Linux kernel, a function named `put_` generally means "freeing" or "releasing" something. (As "put" is the opposite of "get"). From a brief look through the code, it appears that function is called to release a `struct page`.

The (related) function [`put_pages_list`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/mm/swap.c?v=3.14#L306) is actually documented:

```
/**
 * put_pages_list() - release a list of pages
 * @pages: list of pages threaded on page->lru
 *
 * Release a list of pages which are strung together on page.lru.  Currently
 * used by read_cache_pages() and related error recovery code.
 */
```

To me, this confirms that `put_page` "releases" a single `struct page`.

Answer (score 2):

A "put_page" will copy the page to transcendent memory and associate it with the type and
offset associated with the page.

A "get_page" will copy the page, if found, from transcendent memory into kernel memory, but will NOT remove the page from from transcendent memory.

See the Linux kernel doc: [frontswap.txt](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/vm/frontswap.txt) for details.

Answer (score 1):

I just [found this](http://niaz-mm.blogspot.com/2011/12/discussion-on.html) which seems very succinct & useful:

> There are two phases of these functions:
>
> 1. delete the page from lru cache (__page_cache_release)
> 2. freeing the page to memory allocator
>
> Consider the allocation process:
>
> 1. page is allocated
> 2. page table entries are fixed
> 3. page is added to lru cache.
>
> In the `put_page` functions, page table entries are not handled. So
>   the control path should fix/remove appropriate page table entries
>   depending before calling thes functions.